# How to make the table border length as per cell data length c#?

Tags: c#, itext

Is it possible to make the border length of a specific table cell fit the contents of that cell?

I did

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total.ToString(),myFont));
cell.Border=PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER;
cell.HorizontalAlignment=Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
tabl.AddCell(cell);
```

But it produces the below result (the top & bottom border exceeds the cell data length/space)

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: Is it really a table structure with multiple columns and/or rows?  Or just 1 cell that is used to get this border effect? If there are multiple elements, what's the expected result if the cell below has longer content: do the top and bottom "border" differ in length?

Comment: @rhens yes it's a table structure with 4 columns and no other cell apart from the one I mentioned in my question will have borders... Since no other cell will have any borders the cell below will also be border less... I hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## iText 7

In iText 7, this is very straightforward, because it's possible out of the box to set borders to any element. In this use case, instead of using table or cell borders, it's easier to set a top and bottom border to the piece of text itself.

```cs
Table table = new Table(4);
table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
// no border on the table
table.SetBorder(null);

// no border on the cell
Cell cell = new Cell().SetBorder(null);
Text t = new Text("410.40");
// top and bottom border on the Text instance
t.SetBorderTop(new SolidBorder(1.5f));
t.SetBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(1.5f));
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().Add(t);
cell.Add(p);
table.AddCell(cell);

// some test cells
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Column 2")).SetBorder(null));
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("C 3")).SetBorder(null));
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("C 4")).SetBorder(null));

doc.Add(table);
```

[image]

## iText 5 / iTextSharp

A bit more grunt work is involved to get the same effect. A possible approach is to use a page event listener and a `Chunk` with a "generic tag" to trigger a page event upon rendering. That callback will expose the rendering rectangle of the Chunk, which allows those coordinates to be used to draw the top and bottom line at the correct location.

```cs
writer.PageEvent = new BorderEvent();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.WidthPercentage = 100;

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
// Use a Chunk with a "generic tag", which triggers a callback when it's rendered
Chunk c = new Chunk("410.40");
c.SetGenericTag("borders");
cell.AddElement(c);
// no border on the cell
cell.Border = 0;
table.AddCell(cell);

// some test cells
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("Column 2"));
cell.Border = 0;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("C 3"));
cell.Border = 0;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("C 4"));
cell.Border = 0;
table.AddCell(cell);

doc.Add(table);
```

The callback for the generic tag:

```cs
class BorderEvent : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document,
            Rectangle rect, String text)
    {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
        // draw the top border, based on the rendering rectangle
        canvas.SetLineWidth(1.5);
        canvas.MoveTo(rect.Left, rect.Top);
        canvas.LineTo(rect.Right, rect.Top);
        // draw the bottom border, based on the rendering rectangle
        // the bottom coordinate is the base line of the text,
        // so some calculation, probably including the font size, is
        // needed to lower it a bit
        // I've used a quick and dirty 3 points here
        canvas.Stroke();
        canvas.MoveTo(rect.Left, rect.Bottom - 3);
        canvas.LineTo(rect.Right, rect.Bottom - 3);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: All the relevant code is only related to iText, so it shouldn't matter if you implement this in a Windows Forms app or in some other way. The page event listener is set on the `PdfWriter`, as shown in the first line of my sample code: `writer.PageEvent = new BorderEvent();`  The `BorderEvent` class is the corresponding implementation.